# three level cascading drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a beginner in programming being stuck the last 2 days on that and i am hopping on your help :)

I am building an mvc 4 app and I have a partial view with a list of departments and when you choose the department you can see the item types for this specific department in a drop down list in Browse view.

What I am trying to make is one more dropdown list in Browse view that will show the items according to the selected department and item types.

So this is my code :

**View :**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Bookings", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TypeItemFormID", data_itemsListAction = @Url.Action("ItemsList") }))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend> Type/Item</legend>
    @Html.DropDownList("department", ViewBag.ItemTypesList as SelectList, "Select a Type", new {id="ItemTypeID"})
    <div id="ItemsDivId">
        <label for="Items">Items </label>
        <select id="ItemsID" name="Items"></select>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type ="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitID" />
    </p>
 </fieldset>
}
<script src ="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/typeItems.js")"></script>
```

**The controller :**

```
public class BookingsController : Controller
    {

        private BookingSystemEntities db = new BookingSystemEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Bookings/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Select your Department";
            var departments = db.Departments.ToList();
            return View(departments);
        }

        public ActionResult Browse(string department, string ID)
        {

            ViewBag.Message = "Browse for Equipment";

           var departments = db.Departments.Include("Items").Single(i => i.DepartmentName == department);

           ViewBag.ItemTypesList = GetItemTypeSelectList(department);

           return View();

        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var item = db.Items.Find(id);

            return View(item);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Home/DepartmentMenu
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult DepartmentMenu()
        {
            var departments = db.Departments.ToList();
            return PartialView(departments);
        }


        public SelectList GetItemTypeSelectList(string department)
        {
            var departments = db.Departments.Include("Items").Single(i => i.DepartmentName == department);
            List<SelectListItem> listItemTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var item in departments.Items.Select(s => s.ItemType.ItemTypeName).Distinct())
            {
                listItemTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = item,
                    Value = item,
                }

                     );
            }

            return new SelectList(listItemTypes.ToArray(),
                                "Text",
                                "Value");

        }

        public ActionResult ItemsList(string ID)
        {
            string Text = ID;
            var items = from s in db.Items
                        where s.ItemType.ItemTypeName == Text
                        select s;

            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return Json(new SelectList(
                                items.ToArray(),
                                "ItemId",
                                "ItemName")
                           , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            return RedirectToAction("Browse");
        } 


    }
```

**The Javascript :**

```
$(function () {

    $('#ItemsDivId').hide();
    $('#SubmitID').hide();

    $('#ItemTypeID').change(function () {
        var URL = $('#TypeItemFormID').data('itemsListAction');
        $.getJSON(URL + '/' + $('#ItemTypeID').val(), function (data) {
            var items = '<option>Select a Item</option>';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                items += "<option value='" + item.Value + "'>" + item.Text + "</option>";
                // state.Value cannot contain ' character. We are OK because state.Value = cnt++;
            });
            $('#ItemsID').html(items);
            $('#ItemsDivId').show();

        });
    });

    $('#ItemsID').change(function () {
        $('#SubmitID').show();
    });
});
```

**And at last my Model :**

```
 public class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Department")]
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }

public class ItemType
    {
        public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Type")]
        public string ItemTypeName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Image")]
        public string ItemTypeImage { get; set; }

        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }

 public class Item
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Description")]
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

         [DisplayName("Ref Code")]
        public string ItemReferenceCode { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ItemType")]
        public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual ItemType ItemType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Department")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Computer Location")]
        public string ComputerLocation { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Author Name")]
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Published Year")]
        public string PublishedYear { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're asking as there isn't actually a question in your post. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I can actually get fine the departments in partial view and then in Browse the item types load fine according to the department in the first drop down list but my third drop down list is just empty and wont load any values at all. I also mentioned that the form wont pick up the method ItemsList ? I was hopping if you can help... I get no errors , just the values in my third drop down list wont load..

Comment: Helpful tip: you'll get quicker help and better answers by using proper grammar and punctuation in your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would accomplish something like this. It isn't the only way to do it.

```
 $('#ItemTypeID').on('change', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTypeForm")',
            data: { itemTypeId: $('#ItemTypeID').val() },
            success: function(results) {
                var options = $('#ItemTypeFormId');
                options.empty();
                options.append($('<option />').val(null).text("- Select an Item Type  -"));
                $.each(results, function() {
                    options.append($('<option />').val(this.ItemTypeFormId).text(this.Value));
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Then you'd have a controller that looks something like this.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetItemTypeForm(string itemTypeId)
    {
        //pseudo code
        var data = Repostitory.GetData(itemTypeId) 

        return Json(data);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me , unfortunately still the third drop down list with the items is empty without any values :(

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging, There's tons of potential places your issue could be coming from.  The issue can be on the javascript side or the controller side.  Put breaks in your controller code and make sure your javascript is calling the appropriate controller method.  Then make sure it's getting appropriate lookup id.  Then make sure it's sending down the appropriate json (use fiddler or chrome developer tools).  If it is then the problem is in how your building the drop down list using javascript.  Make sure the this.{your value name} is matching the json result.